# timezone in Where clause of linq query

Tags: c#, linq, timezone

I'm writing a Where clause to filter a datetime column.

I receive a timezone offset (for example, -9.00 for US PST) and I'm looking to filter all the elements that are within the last x days.

This is what I have so far.
UserTimezone is the parameter that specifies the user's timezone and TheDays is the number of days we want to filter for

```
DateTime TheNow = DateTime.Now;
TheNow = TheNow.AddHours(UserTimezone);

DateTime TheSelectTime = TheNow;

DateTime TheShift = - TheDays * 24;
TheSelectTime = TheSelectTime.AddHours(TheShift);

var TheQuery = from...
               where t.Appoint < TheSelectTime
```

If I write t.Appoint.Date < TheSelectTime.Date then isn't this going to select only based on the date and not the time. What are your suggestions to solve this?

Comment: Cant you use the localization class for current thread/context - whatever?

Comment: possible duplicate of [selecting the correct datetime with timezone in linq query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941428/selecting-the-correct-datetime-with-timezone-in-linq-query)

Comment: @stefan, he probably is dealing with a web request from a web client that operates in a different timezone.

Comment: @digEmAll: yes, the question got posted twice because I had a connection issue; just deleted the dup. Thanks

Comment: @maple_shaft i thought asp.net took care of that automatically i guess i was wrong :)

Comment: @stefan, you may be right actually, but I have run into this problem on multiple platforms and languages that don't provide this for you and I guess I always like to be safe.  Plus I don't see where the OP stated this was an ASP.NET app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to try adding x days to Appoint and see if that is MORE THAN DateTime.Now.

Comment: Does the .Date selector take into consideration the whole datetime with the time or just the actual date. Suppose a record is stored as 5/4/2011 8:00 GMT and that the user is in California (GMT -9): will this record show up in 5/4 or 5/3?

Comment: A DateTime is a value object, and at its core it represents a SINGLE POINT IN TIME regardless of timezone. Your timezone should only affect how one views the DateTime or outputs its value, perhaps in the form of a string.  EDIT: Thus adding 24 days to a DateTime for instance will actually add 24 days worth of time.  If after that time is added it is more than the DateTime.Now time capture, then it is officially EXPIRED.